# Why can BuildProvider be used only with ASP.NET website projects?

Tags: subsonic, buildprovider

I was going to try [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/), you can generate DAL with buildProvider element in an ASP.NET website project. But I get curious why Web applications or windows applications do not support [BuildProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildprovider.aspx).

PS: I know for Subsonic there is one other option to use it with other than BuildProvider, but I just get curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because of the different way things are compiled in web application projects vs. website projects. From what I read on MSDN, it has to do with the fact that in web app projects, all your code files are compiled into a single assembly using MSBuild before deployment, but Build Providers are used to generate code that is compiled at runtime (from your App_Code folder).

In website projects, all of your code is compiled at runtime so it all plays nicely together.

Comment: yes, but I realized that generating code at runtime and compiling it is a nice feature, why cant we use for a windows app? Is there a secret reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly hook it into your pre-build event, and call the sonic.exe with the proper command line.